# Get the closes coordinates to (0,0)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm making a system where I'm drawing a cube and I need to get the correct cordinates. Im trying to calculate the `width` and `height` correctly

There 4 case scenario:

---

- Correct scenario

`x1=10`

`y1=10`

`x2=30`

`y2=40`

`width=(x2-x1)=20`

`height=(x2-x1)=30`

This would be correct as the `x1,y1` are closes to `0,0`

---

- Bad scenario's

`x2=5`

This would result in `Width= -5` and therefore the closes point to 0,0 would no longer be `x1,y1` and an imagery on that dost exist. Same with `y2` or both.

How can I calculate this correctly?

Comment: Can't you just use absolute value to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the closest point to $(0,0)$? It shouldn't be difficult to modify the drawing code to handle negative widths.

Alternatively, assuming that all of the coordinates are positive, you could do something like

```
if(x1 > x2)
  std::swap(x1,x2);
if(y1 > y2)
  std::swap(y1,y2);
```

and then call your old code.